# Android Search Match 2 columns SQL Statement

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, search

I am following the Android SearchableDictionary tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog) and code [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_development/tree/master/samples/SearchableDictionary), I get everything to work, and understand the code. However, for the life of me I cannot make the search look in 2 columns of the searchable sqliteDB. See the comment below for what I want to accomplish

```
public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        //This (original code) searches your query in the KEY_WORD column, which is the SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 column.
        //String selection = KEY_WORD + " MATCH ?";

        // This searches your query across ALL columns of the table, not what I want because I have added additional columns to the sqlitedb table
        //String selection = FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " MATCH ?";

        // This is what I want, to search my query in both the keyword and keydefinition columns, which is the 1 and 2 suggest column text
        String selection = KEY_WORD +"OR" + KEY_DEFINITION+ " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);

        /* This builds a query that looks like:
         *     SELECT <columns> FROM <table> WHERE <KEY_WORD> MATCH 'query*'
         * which is an FTS3 search for the query text (plus a wildcard) inside the word column.
```

Things I have tried (there are more, but they are tiny modifications of the following formats):

`String selection = KEY_WORD +"OR" + KEY_DEFINITION+ " MATCH ?";`

`String selection = FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE+ " MATCH 'suggest_text_1:? OR suggest_text_2:?'";`

I have also read the relevant sections of [this](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), it did not help me because it again gave example of searching in 1 column and searching in all columns using the hidden db named column. I need to search for more than 1 column in a single SQL statement.

Comment: See [the actual documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I actually did read that and it did not help me. I also updated my question with what I tried. It seems to me fts4 can only search for queries in 1 column or all columns? I just need an example where I can search for 2 columns in 1 statement.